# Auto Run Python Script on Servers as Host

Tags: python, webserver

I have a scraping script made with Python (beautiful Soup) that scraps data from few websites and saves the data in CSV files.

I need to run this script every day at a certain times.

I am currently running it locally with Schedule Task.

I was wondering if it is possible to run such scripts on a third party hosting server and what kind of characterstic I should look into this web server for it to work.

I would like to avoid the necessity to automatically switch on my pc every day and instead to let everything happen automatically on-line

I am aware of Django and that you can make dynamic HTML pages with it but mime is a different thing and I can not find information regarding it.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "on a hosting server"? Do you want to host a server on your own computer, or do you mean on an external, third party server? Maybe get a Raspberry Pi, which you can leave on all day, all week, ...?

Comment: I mean a third party server, like where you can post websites.. but I can't see how would you be allowed to run schedule python script on any of those

Comment: Just set up a cronjob

Comment: How is it possible to know that the server I will run the py script on has the libraries I am using (beautiful soup for isntance) installed?